# how to add css class(active) while change the page in zend framework's layout

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework2

layout.phtml

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('login') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Home') ?></a></li>

                       <li class="dropdown">  
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="50" data-close-others="false">
        Jobs <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="<?php echo $this->url('home') ?>">Interviews</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Resume Tips</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Interview Ques</a></li>
    </ul>
</li> 
               <li class="" id="com"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('company') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('HR Desk') ?></a></li>
               <li class=""><a href="<?php echo $this->url('home') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Job Tips') ?></a></li>    
               <li class=""><a href="<?php echo $this->url('home') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Contact Us') ?></a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </nav>
```

what and where should i do change the class when change the page to add the css class(active)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 ways php and javascript:

php on the onBootStrap method you have to get the view and add a variable like: "selectedSection" then on every view check if == then echo active on the class attribute of every li.

otherwise, add a jquery like

```
  $('li#com').addClass('active');
```

at the end of every view.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
Set active variable from controller and show in view page

```
    In controller:
    $this->layout()->setVariable('login_active', 'active');
This $login_active will get in layout
```

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="<?php echo $this->login_active; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('login') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Home') ?></a></li>

                <li class="dropdown <?php echo $this->view->job_active; ?>">  
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="50" data-close-others="false">
                        Jobs <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="<?php echo $this->url('home') ?>">Interviews</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Resume Tips</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Interview Ques</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li> 
                <li class="<?php echo $this->company_active; ?>" id="com"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('company') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('HR Desk') ?></a></li>
                <li class="<?php echo $this->home_active; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('home') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Job Tips') ?></a></li>    
                <li class="<?php echo $this->another_page_active; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('home') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Contact Us') ?></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Solution 2:** 
Compare controller name from view and assign active class

```
In view:
$controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$action = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

Comment: But the layout is before the view. so if you set the variable at view level you will never get it at layout level :)

Comment: I haven't but I had to pass a variable menu into the layout some time ago on zf2 and I couldn't access controller variables from the layout. hopefully you are right :)

Comment: Sorry, I though you are using zend 1. Please ignore my comment and set variable to layout.         $this->layout()->setVariable('name', 'anjith'); You will get 'anjith' as value of $name

Comment: can you give some more explaination on solution:2 please...@AnjithKP